# Calculate volume of dent in a 3D mesh

Tags: 3d, volume, mesh

I'm considering a problem and wanted to ask if there's any common way to solve it.

Let's say I have a square mesh of a plate. Somewhere in that plate there is a dent (where a dent is a deformation of the plate that's going inside, building a cavelike structure).

Now I'd like to measure the volume of that dent. Can I do this in a simple way (e.g. with Meshlab)?

What would be a good Framework to tackle this ? I heard about VTK. Would this be an overkill?

Thanks :)

Comment: in what form is your mesh ? file-format,platform ??? if you have simple enough access to it than solve it in C++/or whatever (Volume computation of flat surface with dents is easy integration/summation of base plane distortions ... two nested loops with single addition in it)